# eth0 interface is missing

Tags: networking, gentoo

I have a new Gentoo server installed on virtual, with virtual lan interface. When booting from live CD, network (eth0) is available. When booting into the newly-created system, the network is missing at startup. The interface is shown in dmesg. In `ifconfig`, `eth0` is missing.

What's wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: use `ip link show` and put your output here.

Comment: I can't get text only output... i must inserted here as a picture... for this time... Later I investigate how get text output from ms virtual machine.

Comment: ip likn show is in the picture up.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Thanks for contributing! But please, don't post images of text ([read this for reasons why](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)).

Comment: I understand difference bwtween picture and text output.. But it's no way how to get text from ms virtual without network and ssl acces to putty or some other external consolas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the poorly translated kernel. Bad config file caused that the changes associated with enabling virtualization options did not take effect.

After repairing and rebuilding the new kernel, eth0 is available and the net working perfect.

Answer (score 1):

your interface is bond0 
just use this command dhclient to get the IP from your VM's DHCP server

```
dhclient
```

Comment: uf... In installation process there was thre interfaces, lo, bound0, eth0. After reboot eth0 missined... I thinked, that bound0 is for network bounding... Ok. I test configure bond0 as eth0 and see if it will be ok. Thx.

Comment: you're welcome
if you have any problem to your interface name you can change this
vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bound0
and change the DEVICE name to eth0 and reset the networks service

Comment: Did you (both) mean `bond0` instead of `bound0`?

Comment: Yes. bond0. (bound0 was my mistake)

Comment: I have no path /etc/sysconfig...

Comment: yes :))))))))))

Comment: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:X86/Full/Networking

Comment: Okay. I'll look at this link for the third time. Maybe I missed something. :-)

Comment: Even if bonding is enabled, why would the raw interface disappear? (I mean, that's not how it worked when I've used it.) Or, alternatively, why would something rename the interface?

Comment: Ok. Problem is still actual. I thing that error is that gentoo not find Ethernet adapter. Find when booting (ethernet adapter see screen up...) but not create interface and not assign it to bond0 or eth0. Because eth0 ethernet is missing and bond0 not pingnig, I'am not able to acces ip it etc...

Comment: In my gentoo installation dhclient is misssing and I have nothing like this in packages. I use dhcpcd but in same result... bond0 have no ip address. When booting from livecd, lo, bond0 and eth0 are present. And eth0 have dhcp address.

Comment: I also installed lspci (pciutils) and I don't see any eth interface in it.

Comment: the result is: dhcpcd bond0... bond0 waiting for carrier... timeout... dhcpcd exited.

Answer (score 0):

Your ethernet is `bond0`, You can do it:
`ip address add NEW_IP dev bond0` 
Of course you need to specify gateway such as :
`ip route add  default via YOUR_DEFAULT_GATEWAY dev bond0`

Or if you have DHCP server you need to run `dhclient bond0`

Comment: Even if bonding is enabled, why would the raw interface disappear? (I mean, that's not how it worked when I've used it.) Or, alternatively, why would something rename the interface?